# Morse Theory and proper actions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is  there  some  reference  containing  an  ellaboration  of  Morse  Theory  for  proper  actions  of  Lie  groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at

> N. Hingston, *Equivariant Morse theory and closed geodesics*, 
>   J. Differential Geom.
>   Volume 19, Number 1 (1984), 1-276.

in particular Section 2. Most statements from the equivariant Morse theory for compact group actions go over unchanged, thanks to the existence of slices for proper actions; see

> R. Palais, *On the existence of slices for actions of noncompact Lie groups*,
>   Ann. of Math. 73
>   (1961)295-323.